# fetching milliseconds from date column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have a table `t1(v_dt date)` . i have to insert the values in this column as

```
2018/05/07 19:41:34:045
2018/05/07 19:41:34:049
```

i am using below conversion function in control file to load the table. but the results are not as expected as it should come `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:SSS` format.

```
CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(v_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF3') AS TIMESTAMP)
```

any idea how to achieve this .. Thanks

Comment: date does not support to store fraction of second

Comment: i have changed the datatype to TIMESTAMP but i want to use this field as primary key but it is throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

As [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) says: This data type contains the datetime fields such as YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. **It does not have fractional seconds.**

If you want to keep precision, you should change column datatype from `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP` in your table.